# Modelling a tree of entities each with common and specific properties

Tags: sql, tree

I'm trying to model a set of entities for an SQL / Java application.

I will have to handle different entities, like cars, trucks, drones and boats.

All these entities are in fact an equipment. And one equipment can depend on another one, say a trailer to a truck.

I could have only one equipment entity, referencing itself in case of a dependence of an equipment on another one.

But, if these equipment will have common properties, like parent_id, serial_number, they will also have very different properties, and having so many and so differing properties in one entity will bloat it.

I would prefer to have the specific entities for each kind of equipment, one for the boats, one for the trucks, etc...

I wonder how to model this in terms of SQL tables.

Any tip ?

Comment: That depends on many variables. for instance, how often do you introduce a new type of equipment to the system?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Let's say I start with 3 types of equipment, each with between 15 and 20 specific properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This started out as a comment but it's turning out to be way too long, so here goes:

First, in order to properly answer this question one must have as much data as possible - a complete spec of the data that needs to be stored is best, of course. Even worst, get a couple of expert DBAs, give them the exact same data, and you might find yourself with two very different approaches. Having said that I'll try to answer your question as best I can.

There is a trade-off between the flexibility of the EAV anti-pattern and the security of setting a table for each equipment type. There are other ways to design the database, such as "inheritance" - where you have one base table for equipment, that holds all *common* attributes, and a different table for each specific type of equipment, linked with a 1:1 relationship with the base equipment table, to hold all *unique* attributes.
This is the reason I've asked in the comments how **often** you introduce a new type of equipment to the system - because if it's done in a high frequency you might want to consider something like EAV, but if it's a low frequency then I would suggest using a different table for each equipment.

As for the question of using the base equipment table or not - it depends on other factors such as - Are there attributes that needs to be linked in foreign keys to all equipment type? One example I can think of in the context of this question is `manufacturer`, or even `colors` - These are both attributes that should be common to all equipment types you wrote about, but also need to be in 1:M relationship - Each truck is made by a single manufacturer, but the same manufacturer might also make cars or boats, and everything have at least one base color.

Comment: I'll avoid the EAV pattern. As for having a base equipment table, you say it depends on some factors, showing one of them. Considering only this one factor, does the need for common-to-all foreign key attributes advocate for using or for avoiding a base table ?

Comment: Not enough to decide. If they all are on the many side, then yes. if they all are in the one side, than no.